# Virtual terminal switched when USB mouse plugged in Linux

Tags: linux, xorg, usb, console

Our machine runs a modified RedHat 9 (Kernel Linux 2.6.20-1.21, GNOME 2.10.0). When USB mouse is plugged in, the X Window will always switch out, we have to switch back by Alt + F7. There is no such problem with PS2 mouse.

So, one line was added into */etc/udev/rules.d/15-mouse.rules*:

```
KERNEL=="mouse", BUS=="usb", SYSFS{product}=="Mouse", MODE="0660", NAME="input/mouse0", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chvt 8; chvt 7'"
```

But these days, we found this doesn't work for 2 machines. I have to use Alt + F9 to switch back to X Window.

I am new to this, can anybody help me to understand:

1. Why virtual terminals are switched when USB mouse is plugged in?
2. I thought #7 virtual terminal is used for X window, why it is changed to #9?

Thank you.

Comment: @warl0ck Not sure. This is for an old product, which runs only this modified Red Hat 9. I'll test with a new distro.

Comment: 1. The vt switch when plugging in a mouse looks like an X server bug.

Answer (score 1):

**I thought #7 virtual terminal is used for X window, why it is changed to #9?**

You can start your X window system on an arbitrary virtual terminal. There is no restriction. To change that on your current setup you have to look at the configuration/initialization file of your display manager. For example if you use `xdm` you can define on which `vt` you want to start your X server in `/etc/X11/xdm/Xservers`. In this case the line of interest looks like

```
:0 local /usr/bin/X :0 vt<no> -nolisten tcp
```

Where `<no>` is the number of the virtual terminal on which you want to start the X-server. For other display managers the approach is a similar.

It is important that the number of the `vt` must be different from the numbers of those terminals `getty` is bound to. Usually the first six vt's are bound to `getty` so in most cases a number greater than six is just fine.

To test that the used `vt` is really arbitrary you can start another instance of your standard X server on another `vt` by

```
xinit -- :99 vt8
```

This, for example starts a new instance on `vt8` if display number `99` isn't already in use.